# Good examples of Clojure macros usage which demonstrate advantages of the language over the mainstream?

Tags: macros, clojure

I am thinking about learning Clojure, but coming from the c-syntax based (java, php, c#) world of imperative languages that's going to be a challenge, so one naturally asks oneself, is it really worth it? And while such question statement can be very subjective and hard to manage, there is one specific trait of Clojure (and more generally, the lisps) that I keep reading about, that is supposed to make it the most flexipowerful language ever: the macros.

Do you have any good examples of macro usage in Clojure, for purposes which in other mainstream languages (consider any of C++, PHP, Perl, Python, Groovy/Java, C#, JavaScript) would require much less elegant solutions/a lot of unnecessary abstraction/hacks/etc.

Comment: Take a look here at some cool macros: http://blog.klipse.tech/clojure/2016/05/09/macro-tutorial-4.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

there are a lot of macros in the base of clojure that you don't think about... Which is a sign of a good macro, they let you **extend the language in ways that make life easier.** With out macros life would be much less exciting. for instance if we didn't have

```
(with-out-str (somebody else's code that prints to screen))
```

then you would need to modify their code in ways that you may not have access to.

another great example is

```
(with-open-file [fh (open-a-file-code ...)]
   (do (stuff assured that the file won't leak)))
```

the whole `with-something-do` pattern of macros have really added to the clojure eco system.

---

the other side of the proverbial macro coin is that I spend essentially all of my (current) professional Clojure time using a very macro heavy library and thus i spend a lot of time **working around the fact that macros don't compose well and are not first class**. The authors of this library are going to great lengths in the next version to make all the functionality available with out going through the macros to allow people like me to use them in higher order functions like `map` and `reduce`.

macros improve the world when they make life easier. They can have the opposite effect when they are the only interface to a library. **please don't use macros as interfaces**

It is hard in general to get the shape of  your data truly correct. If as a library author, you have the data structured well for how you envision your library being used it may very well be that there is a way to re-structure things to allow users to employ your library in new and unimaginable ways. In this case the structure of the fantastic library in question was really quite good, it allowed for things the authors had not intended. Unfortunatly a great library was restricted because it's interface was a set of macros not a set of functions. **the library was better than it's macros, so they held it back**. This is not to say that macros are in any way to blame, just that programming is hard and they are another tool that can have many effects and all the pieces must be used together to work well.

Comment: Damn! I was just writing an answer along these lines, so I'll just +1 this one :) P.S. I think in clojure the macro is `with-open`.

Comment: Could you explain your second example? What do you mean by leak? About using macros as interfaces, in your opinion, do you think this was just a very bad decision on part of the authors of the library, or do clojure macros just work in such way that it is too easy to overuse them for anyone but a very skilled developer?

Comment: Although `with-out-str` really is a great convenience, it's not the macro aspect here that is key. The key are **dynamic bindings** and the fact that `*out*` is such a dynamically bound var. Macro just makes it easier to delimit the part of code where `*out*` is rebound to a `StringWriter`.

Answer (score 25):

I find macros pretty useful for defining new language features. In most languages you would need to wait for a new release of the language to get new syntax - in Lisp you can just extend the core language with macros and add the features yourself.

For example, Clojure doesn't have a imperative C-style `for(i=0 ;i<10; i++)` loop but you can easily add one with a macro:

```
(defmacro for-loop [[sym init check change :as params] & steps]
  (cond
    (not (vector? params)) 
      (throw (Error. "Binding form must be a vector for for-loop"))
    (not= 4 (count params)) 
      (throw (Error. "Binding form must have exactly 4 arguments in for-loop"))
    :default
      `(loop [~sym ~init value# nil]
         (if ~check
           (let [new-value# (do ~@steps)]
             (recur ~change new-value#))
           value#))))
```

Usage as follows:

```
(for-loop [i 0, (< i 10), (inc i)]
  (println i))
```

Whether it is a good idea to add an imperative loop to a functional language is a debate we should probably avoid here :-)

Comment: Nice, this is the kind of stuff I was looking for. (if (have-more you) (please-continue)) ;)

Comment: My clojure-utils library on GitHub has a steadily growing collection of similar macros and functions: https://github.com/mikera/clojure-utils

Answer (score 15):

There's also a more esoteric use case for macros that I sometimes use: writing concise, readable code that is also fully optimized. Here's a trivial example:

```
(defmacro str* [& ss] (apply str (map eval ss)))
```

What this does is concatenate strings at compile time (they have to be compile-time constants, of course). The regular string concatenation function in Clojure is `str` so wherever in a tight-loop code I have a long string that I would like to break up into several string literals, I just add the star to `str` and change runtime concatenation to compile-time. Usage:

```
(str* "I want to write some very lenghty string, most often it will be a complex"
      " SQL query. I'd hate if it meant allocating the string all over every time"
      " this is executed.")
```

Another, less trivial example:

```
(defmacro jprint [& xs] `(doto *out* ~@(for [x xs] `(.append ~x))))
```

The `&` means it accepts a variable number of arguments (varargs, variadic function). In Clojure a variadic function call makes use of a heap-allocated collection to transfer the arguments (like in Java, which uses an array). This is not very optimal, but if I use a macro like above, then there's no function call. I use it like this:

```
(jprint \" (json-escape item) \")
```

It compiles into three invocations of `PrintWriter.append` (basically an unrolled loop).

Finally, I would like to show you something even more radically different. You can use a macro to assist you in defining a clas of similar functions, eliminating **vast** amounts of boilerplate. Take this familiar example: in an HTTP-client library we want a separate function for each of the HTTP methods. Every function definition is quite complex as it has four overloaded signatures. Also, each function involves a different request class from the Apache HttpClient library, but everything else is exactly the same for all HTTP methods. Look how much code I need to handle this.

```
(defmacro- def-http-method [name]
  `(defn ~name
     ([~'url ~'headers ~'opts ~'body]
        (handle (~(symbol (str "Http" (s/capitalize name) ".")) ~'url) ~'headers ~'opts ~'body))
     ([~'url ~'headers ~'opts] (~name ~'url ~'headers ~'opts nil))
     ([~'url ~'headers] (~name ~'url ~'headers nil nil))
     ([~'url] (~name ~'url nil nil nil))))

(doseq [m ['GET 'POST 'PUT 'DELETE 'OPTIONS 'HEAD]]
  (eval `(def-http-method ~m)))
```

Comment: +1 for some good macro uses. I may steal some of these ideas, especially like the loop unrolling trick!

Comment: Fun fact: there are whole special purpose Lisps built around this idea. GOAL/GOOL are fully compiled Lisps that generate optimized assembly code. They were the main tools in production of some console games.

Answer (score 7):

Some actual code from a project I was working on -- I wanted nested for-esque loops using unboxed ints.

```
(defmacro dofor
  [[i begin end step & rest] & body]
  (when step
    `(let [end# (long ~end)
           step# (long ~step)
           comp# (if (< step# 0)
                   >
                   <)]
       (loop [~i ~begin]
         (when (comp# ~i end#)
           ~@(if rest
               `((dofor ~rest ~@body))
               body)
           (recur (unchecked-add ~i step#)))))))
```

Used like

```
(dofor [i 2 6 2
        j i 6 1]
  (println i j))
```

Which prints out

```
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
4 4
4 5
```

It compiles to something very close to the raw `loop`/`recur`s that I was originally writing out by hand, so there is basically no runtime performance penalty, unlike the equivalent

```
(doseq [i (range 2 6 2)
        j (range i 6 1)]
  (println i j))
```

I think that the resulting code compares rather favorably to the java equivalent:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 6; i+=2) {
    for (int j = i; j < 6; j++) {
        System.out.println(i+" "+j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple example of a useful macro that is rather hard to re-create without macros is `doto`. It evaluates its first argument and then evaluates the following forms, inserting the result of the evaluation as their first argument. This might not sound like much, but...

With `doto` this:

```
(let [tmpObject (produceObject)]
 (do
   (.setBackground tmpObject GREEN)
   (.setThis tmpObject foo)
   (.setThat tmpObject bar)
   (.outputTo tmpObject objectSink)))
```

Becomes that:

```
(doto (produceObject)
   (.setBackground GREEN)
   (.setThis foo)
   (.setThat bar)
   (.outputTo objectSink))
```

The important thing is that `doto` is not magic - you can (re-)build it yourself using the standard features of the language.

Comment: So this is basically like "with" statement in JS and a couple of other languages?

Comment: @Cray Yes, it is a "with" that you can implement yourself without diving into the compiler sources to change the syntax that it recognizes.

Comment: Note also that `doto` works with anything that conforms to the same syntax -- method invocation is just one use case.

Comment: @Marko True, `doto` works equally well with plain functions and with other macros although it's probably most often used for setting lots of properties on a java object.

Comment: I just thought it helpful to OP to note that generality.

Answer (score 3):

Macros are part of Clojure but IMHO do not believe they are why you should or should not learn Clojure. Data immutability, good constructs to handle concurrent state, and the fact it's a JVM language and can harness Java code are three reasons. If you can find no other reason to learn Clojure, consider the fact that a functional programming language probably should positively affect how you approach problems in any language.

To look at macros, I suggest you start with Clojure's threading macros: thread-first and thread-last `->` and `->>` respectively; visit [this page](http://clojure.org/macros), and many of the [various blogs that discuss Clojure](http://planet.clojure.in) .

Good luck, and have fun.